# Pressing a button sends text to a cell in a separate table view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm currently creating a project that consists of:

- revealViewController
- Main View Controller (4 buttons that show Sub view controllers)
- 4 Sub view controllers
- Table View Controller (Slide-Out Panel)

I'd like to send a text (i.e. "button") to a cell in the 1st section on the table view controller on pressing a specific button (i.e.button #1) on a Sub view controller.

How do I go about doing this? The buttons are not in the table view controller, but a separate view controller.

**SubViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class SubViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func button1action(_ sender: Any) {


        //Pressing this button should send this text "button #1 pressed" to the cell in the TableViewController

        //i.e. A new cell with the text "button #1 pressed" should appear on my table in the first section

    }

}
```

**TableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "add new item"

        return cell
    }
}
```

**MainViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var SlideOutPanel: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        SlideOutPanel.target = self.revealViewController()
        SlideOutPanel.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you click the button do you perform a `segue`?

Comment: yes it does perform a segue

Comment: So if I understand what you asked. You have two viewControllers. ATable and BView. BView has a button when clicked will send a value to ATable so when you perform a navigation back you are able to see the updated value - why don't you just pass it using `performForSegue`?

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter` is this case. Btw, how are you initialising the Slide/Side Menu Panel?

Comment: Torewin: the table is actually a side menu

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in different different way one of is you can use Protocols and pass data from your SubViewController to TableViewController

```
protocol TableViewControllerProtocol: class {
    func passData(With message:String)
}
```

and your SubViewController page create object of your protocol

```
var delegate : TableViewControllerProtocol?

@IBAction func button1action(_ sender: Any) {
     delegate.passData(message: "button #1 pressed")
}
```

and in TableViewController page define protocol and create protocol method and use it

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController ,TableViewControllerProtocol {

            func passData(With message:String){
               print(message)
            }
}
```

but do not forgot to assign TableViewController object to SubViewController delegate object other wise app will crash

Comment: the delegate is not assigned, like `abc.delegate = self`

Comment: And btw OP is asking the send data from Table View Controller to View Controller, whereas Table is working as a Side/Slide Menu Panel.

Comment: How can I assign TableViewController object to SubViewController delegate object?

Comment: where you push or present or setup menu with object of  view controller at that time you can pass delegate object like this let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UIViewController")!
        nextVC.delegate = self

Comment: Pratik

I tried the method as you've suggested but i still don't see the message "button #1 pressed" on the table.

Comment: you can pass delegate = self